# Separating Rects Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Essentially, what I'm doing is placing a bunch of random width/height rects onto a grid (near the center of it), then pushing them all away from each other until none of them overlap. I have another version where I check for collisions before I place them on the grid, but that's not what I'm going for in this build.

I'm wondering if someone can explain a better way to go about this?

What I've tried so far is something similar to:

let r1/r2 = rect1/rect2

```
do {
    var ox = Math.max(0, Math.min(r1.x + r1.w, r2.x + r2.w) - Math.max(r1.x, r2.x)),
        oy = Math.max(0, Math.min(r1.y + r1.h, r2.y + r2.h) - Math.max(r1.y, r2.y)),
        dx = r2.x - r1.x,
        dy = r2.y - r1.y;
    if (ox > 0 && oy > 0) {
        if (ox >= oy) {
            if (r1.x >= r2.x && Math.random() > .1) {
                r1.x += ox;
                spaced = true;
                continue;
            } else {
                r1.x -= ox;
                spaced = true;
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            if (r1.y >= r2.y && Math.random() > .1) {
                r1.y += oy;
                spaced = true;
                continue;
            } else {
                r1.y -= oy;
                spaced = true;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
} while ( /* stuff */ )
```

the random is only there because I will run into times when a certain rect gets pushed back and forth and never gets free and causes an infinite loop. This way is horribly inefficient however.

Comment: So what is your question? Are you looking for a more efficient algorithm? Are you wondering why without the random you get an infinite loop? Right now it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Wondering if someone can explain a better way to do this, or lead me to a better solution

Comment: TL:DR - does it need to end up as a "grid" or do you want to arrange the rects as tightly as possible?

Comment: the latter, arrange them tightly, but it doesn't need to fill in all the space in between the rects

Comment: If you want to minimize the bounding rectangle, your problem is effectively [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455392/find-smallest-area-that-contains-all-the-rectangles). Or is the bounding circle you want to minimize?

Comment: You have rectangles that are overlapping and by the code that you h ave posted you are checking and resolving pairwise that not any of the rectangles be intersecting. Quick question: What has the grid go to do with it any of this ? You haven't used the dimmensions of the grid anywhere in this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your trying to accomplish is known as a packing problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem. If you just search stack overflow for "2d bin packing" you should be able to find all you need to roll a much more efficient algorithm.